# Manual product with unknown number of arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, cartesian-product

The following examples give the same result:

A.

```
product = []
for a in "abcd":
    for b in "xy":
        product.append((a,b))
```

B.

```
from itertools import product
list(product("abcd","xy"))
```

How can I calculate the cartesian product like in example A when I don't know the number of arguments n?

**REASON I'm asking this:**

Consider this piece of code:

```
allocations = list(product(*strategies.values()))
for alloc in allocations:
    PWC[alloc] = [a for (a,b) in zip(help,alloc) if coalitions[a] >= sum(b)]
```

The values of the `strategies` dictionary are list of tuples, `help` is an auxiliary variable (a list  with the same length of every `alloc`) and `coalitions` is another dictionary that assigns to the tuples in help some numeric value.

Since strategies values are sorted, I know that the if statement won't be true anymore after a certain `alloc`. Since allocations is a pretty big list, I would avoid tons of comparisons and tons of sums if I could use the example algorithm A.

Comment: What exactly speaks against using `itertools.product` for this?

Comment: Because in this case, the values of b (let's consider only the last element of each alloc) will be tuples like: (0.0.1),(0.0.2),(0.0.3) etc. (long to explain why). Instead coalitions[a] is a constant. If coalitions[a] = 3, I know that after b = (0.0.3), all the next values of a must not be included in PWC[alloc].

Comment: I don’t really get it. Is it that you want to cancel iterating further elements from the cartesian product at some point? In that case, how does using a list comprehension as in A help you to do that at all?

Comment: sorry, forget about the list comprehension and think about nested loops (I'll edit right away). I need all elements of the cartesian products. Each element is a key inside the PWC dictionary. Each key redirects to a list and the existence of each nth element of such lists depend on the sum of the nth element of the key (it's a tuple of tuples). While such sum is smaller than a certain constant, that element must go inside the list. Since I know that the sum keeps increasing for each iteration, once it hits the limit, I don't need to check the sum anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to abort the allocations after you hit a certain condition, and you want to avoid generating all the elements from the cartesian product for those, then simply don’t make a list of all combinations in the first place.

`itertools.product` is *lazy* that means that it will only generate a single value of the cartesian product at a time. So you never need to generate all elements, and you also never need to compare the elements then. Just don’t call `list()` on the result as that would iterate the whole sequence and store all possible combinations in memory:

```
allocations = product(*strategies.values())
for alloc in allocations:
    PWC[alloc] = [a for (a,b) in zip(help,alloc) if coalitions[a] >= sum(b)]

    # check whether you can stop looking at more values from the cartesian product
    if someCondition(alloc):
        break
```

It’s just important to note how `itertools.product` generates the values, what pattern it follows. It’s basically equivalent to the following:

```
for a in firstIterable:
    for b in secondIterable:
        for c in thirdIterable:
            …
                for n in nthIterable:
                    yield (a, b, c, …, n)
```

So you get an increasing pattern from the left side of your iterables. So make sure that you order the iterables in a way that you can correctly specify a break condition.

Comment: It's basically equivalent, but not totally identical (I read in the docs the algorithm). Maybe I'm not explaining this well (I'm sure if I could talk to you face to face it would be way easier), but you gave me an idea, so I will accept this answer anyways. But could you please answer my question? Is it possible to use method A for n elements? I don't know if it's just not pythonic or it's directly impossible in python.

Comment: No, you can’t really write nested for loops with an arbitrary depth. That doesn’t work, syntactically. You could only do it similar like `itertools` works internally. And by “basically equivalent” I mean that it’s functionally identical. `itertools.product` will only generate one result at a time without storing intermediate results.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
items = ["abcd","xy"]

from itertools import product
list(product(*items))
```

The list `items` can contain an arbitrary number of strings and it'll the calculation with `product` will provide you with the Cartesian product of those strings.

Note that you don't have to turn it into a list - you can iterate over it and stop when you no longer wish to continue:

```
for item in product(*items):
    print(item)
    if condition:
        break
```

Comment: The way I understood the question, OP was explicitely asking for a way to do it like their solution A, i.e. without `itertools.product` (for some unknown reason).